# Change everyone image source to load smaller version

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I would like to change source of every image on my website (`<img>` and `background-image`). What should I do to not load those big images but to change source to load smaller versions from another folder? Simple:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', '/small'+src);
});
```

Will this work?

Comment: why you need to change large image to small image?  you can using bootstrap Img tag you get Responsiveness of any image...here is example fo img responsiveness.......http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_img_thumbnail2&stacked=h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. The browser will first load the large images, and if you achieve the correct code (the above code would not suffice), it will then load the new ones.

I would personally recommend using the new `<picture>` tag, and let the browser choose the image it needs based on the viewport and the device it's browsing from.

[Here is more information about the  element in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work. This script will probably run after your page has been loaded in the browser. So, all the images would have already been loaded into browser before running this script.

Consider changing your server side code for this, or use a lazy loading library such as [this](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).